# Eclipse: GNU toolchain - C files compiled with g++, duplicate GNU C

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, gnu-toolchain

I've added a GNU toolchain in (modified) Eclipse and I'm having the issue of ***.c files being compiled with g++ instead of gcc**.

I've tried:

1. Tweaking the **C/C++ General -> File Types** project properties page. This establishes the connection **file-extension -> file-type** (e.g. ***.c -> C Source File**).
2. Tweaking the **C/C++ General -> Language Mappings** project properties page. This one continues the chain from **file-type -> language-type** (e.g. **C Source File -> GNU C**).
3. Resetting up the toolchain, a few times :)

So what I have now is ***.c -> C Source File -> GNU C**. I'm guessing somewhere (maybe toolchain settings which I couldn't find, configuration files?) there's also currently a **GNU C -> g++.exe** connection. I need to change that to **GNU C -> gcc.exe**:

I also see a **duplicate** entry of **GNU C** at **C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> Languages**.

[image]

I'm hoping someone has hit a similar issue and can give me some (highly appreciated) hints.

Update:

I've also noticed a tool-conflict issue when inspecting the toolchain tool-list:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what weird Eclipse bug causes this, but found a workaround.

Use the MinGW GCC toolchain instead (ignore the benign warning in the image, yet another Eclipse CDT bug):

[image]

and set **MINGW_HOME**, **MSYS_HOME** and PATH manually to the wanted values:

[image]